# How to change the background color of ion-header without the border showing in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I can say I successfully implement other colours to the ion-header, **but how I will remove the border without it being global to the mobile application is the problem.** How do I go about this?

Below is all I tried:

Added white to my variable.scss **src/theme/variable.scss**:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  white:      #fff
);
```

Am now able to append colour white to it. **src/pages/login.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="white">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>  <!--menuToggle removed and ion button hidden. You don't wanna show menu when they are yet to sign in-->
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

But the border still shows. I don't want the boarder to show.

Comment: would have delete the whole ion-header block, but I want to put a word or small logo there without the border demarcating it as navbar showing.

Comment: Can you simulate it on  `stackblitz` https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out just by passing `no-border` into `<ion-header>` ionic element. That removes the border.

So based on the code posted in the question, **src/pages/login.html** becomes:

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-navbar color="white">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>  <!--menuToggle removed and ion button hidden. You don't wanna show menu when they are yet to sign in-->
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```